# PostgreSQL: `unnest` an array and then `array_agg` it back

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

My goal is to take an `array`, unnest it into a table with `unnest` and then aggregate it back into an array with `array_agg`. Why does the first `DO` block fail and the second succeed?

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    x numrange[] := '{"[0, 3]", "[0, 1]", "[3, 5]", "[3, 8]"}';
BEGIN

    x := (SELECT array_agg(x) FROM unnest(x));
    RAISE NOTICE '%', x;
END;
$$;


DO $$
DECLARE
    x numrange[] := '{"[0, 3]", "[0, 1]", "[3, 5]", "[3, 8]"}';
BEGIN

    x := (SELECT array_agg(y) FROM unnest(x) AS y);
    RAISE NOTICE '%', x;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I would like to sort the ranges in the array by descending right boundaries. I am thinking of making a table and sorting it with upper() or something

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name here is my comment recast into a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954733/postgresql-sort-an-array-of-elements-using-some-sorting-condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In first `DO` name of the column is `unnest`. You don't have column `x`.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    x numrange[] := '{"[0, 3]", "[0, 1]", "[3, 5]", "[3, 8]"}';
BEGIN

    x := (SELECT array_agg(unnest) FROM unnest(x));
    RAISE NOTICE '%', x;
END;
$$;
```

---

In second `DO` name of the column is `y` and You can do `string_agg()` on this column.