# PostgreSQL: sort an array of elements using some sorting condition

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sorting, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

Suppose you need to sort an array of `numranges` by, say, descending left boundary. Is the following approach the simplest: `unnest` the array into a table, sort the table, `array_agg` it back into an array. How would that look in code? Here is my non-working attempt:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    x numrange[] := '{"[0, 3]", "[0, 1]", "[3, 5]", "[3, 8]"}';
BEGIN

    x := (
          WITH x AS (
              SELECT xrow FROM unnest(x) AS xrow
          )
          SELECT array_agg(xrow) FROM x ORDER BY lower(xrow) DESC
    );
    RAISE NOTICE '%', x;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must move `ORDER BY` into aggregate function, to afect aggragate order see [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    x numrange[] := '{"[0, 3]", "[0, 1]", "[3, 5]", "[3, 8]"}';
BEGIN

    x := (WITH x AS (
            SELECT xrow FROM unnest(x) AS xrow
        )
        SELECT array_agg(xrow  ORDER BY lower(xrow) DESC) FROM x

    );
    RAISE NOTICE '%', x;
END;
$$;
```